# reading an integer from a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, integer, strtol

I have a code which suppose to read an integer from a file. But its actually reading as an character. Suggest me some modification where I can read the integers into an array.

```
fptr =fopen("path","r");

while(1)
{
  c=getc(fptr);
  putchar(c);
  if (c==EOF)
    exit(1);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv ) {
    int value;
    FILE *fp = fopen ( "d:\\abc.txt", "r");
    while ( fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) == 1 ) {       
        printf ( "%d\n", value );
    }
    fclose ( fp );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fscanf` like this :

```
int a;

while (fscanf(fptr, "%d", &a) == 1)
{
    printf("Read %d\n", a);
}
```